# Should you declare a constant value as a private variable if only using its value once?

Tags: c#, coding-style, private-members

So I have a formatting question. I have a Consumer Model that has once method that forms the consumer model data into a string. Each field has its own defined length:

```
public class ConsumerModel
{
    public string ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string GenerateConsumerString()
    {
        var request = FormatRequestField(ConsumerId, 12);
        request += FormatRequestField(FirstName, 15);
        request += FormatRequestField(LastName, 20);
        return request;
    }
}
```

The method FormatRequestField(string, int) takes the field and returns a string that has been edited/padded to be the length given by the integer. My question is, should the lengths of the fields be stored as private variables? I know this is the normal practice so you don't end up with "mystery" integers - but each integer is only used once. Given that in my actual code there are around 50 properties for this model, that seems like a lot of extra lines of code to store the field lengths as private variables.

I was just wondering what the best practice would be for this situation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd start using constants the first time I found myself having to repeat the numbers. Or are there cases where multiple fields have the same lengths for the same reason, like lines of an address? If you're really, really going to use them only once then your code is self-documenting. It indicates that a first name is fifteen characters. In real life I can imagine having to duplicate those numbers. But I still wouldn't do the extra work until it was needed.

Comment: On a general manner you should declare magic numbers separated from their location. It's easier to maintain your code when you know where your magic numbers are located, and it allows you to reuse those immediately without checking your value in case you had to use those more than once.
About where to declare those, not quite sure if there is a good practice. I've been doing moderately sized electronic oriented projects and I mostly declared those in a fully magic number/define dedicated class Constants which was somehow my electronic-dependant file (data format, pins, ...).

Comment: Depends on if you consider the number to be be an integral part of an instance of that class or just as a variable in your method. Anyway this is very opiniated which is why I´m voting to close this question.

Answer (score 3):

> should the lengths of the fields be stored as private variables?

No, they should be stored as private *constants*. Variables are things that can change; that's why they're called *variables*, because they *vary*.  Constants are things that don't change; that's why they're called *constants*, because they are *constant*.

> I know this is the normal practice so you don't end up with "mystery" integers - but each integer is only used once.

So what?

The purpose of the named constant is not to deduplicate an expression; it's to make the code legible to future developers who read it.

> Given that in my actual code there are around 50 properties for this model, that seems like a lot of extra lines of code to store the field lengths as private variables.

You have a belief that 50 lines of code is "a lot". Fifty lines of code is **nothing**.  Fifty lines of code declaring constants is a few minutes work.  Fifty lines of *constant declarations that never change* is *literally the cheapest fifty lines of code you will write in your career*; why are you hesitating?

> I was just wondering what the best practice would be for this situation.

You already know what the best practice is: avoid magic numbers and make your code legible to future developers.

Answer (score 1):

Besides magic values, readability is very important. Code is read is much more often that it is written, so whatever you can do to help readability, you should do it. For example, you can hide length in a class with constants:

```
public static class FieldWidth
{
    public const int ConsumerId = 12;
    public const int FirstName = 15;
    public const int LastName = 20;
}
```

Read this:

```
var request = FormatRequestField(ConsumerId, 12);
```

And compare:

```
var request = FormatRequestField(ConsumerId, FieldWidth.ConsumerId);
```

Which line contains meaning without you having to go to FormatRequestField and checking what 12 stands for? Which one will be meaningful to you in a month when you forget this code?

Comment: `const string = 12` ?

Comment: Not sure was in my head at that moment.